# How can I add a domain to an IIS 6 SMTP server so that it will relay for that domain?

Tags: windows, email, smtp

How can I add a domain to an IIS 6 SMTP server so that it will relay for that domain?

eg. If I have an email (from address: test@test.com) coming over the net from a server with IP address 1.2.3.4 how can I set my SMTP server to relay this email.

Currently it is getting a 5.1.1 relay denied error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your server sending the mail is different to the one relaying the mail.
IIS SMTP can relay mail from any old machine, and if you don't configure it correctly, anyone can send mail using your machine.  What you have to do is add the IP address of the machine you want to be able to use the SMTP service, under Properties>Access IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the IIS SMTP service will allow you to allow relay for a specific domain name, but it will allow you to provide a list of IP addresses which are allowed to relay through the server (and they would be able to relay for any domain name).  This is under Properties, Access tab, then Relay at the bottom.